# How to find DNS records for all IPs?

Tags: dns

My understanding is that when querying a domain's DNS records, the response can vary depending on the client's IP address. Is there a simple way to obtain all DNS records for all possible IP addresses?

Comment: This might help to an extent: https://www.whatsmydns.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can not.

The response can vary on many factors.

You can not from remote discover the business policies of a nameserver, or in fact any server. It can decide to reply `192.0.2.1` for odd hours and `192.0.2.11` for even ones, or any other non trivial business rule.

A more realistic one: there can be a service on 3 IP addresses. A nameserver may be programmed to reply with the IP address of the box being currently less loaded. Hence you will never be able to see those details remotely.